# Batch script in orientjs does not work

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I am trying to execute a batch script with orientjs as suggested in the [orientjs docs](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientJS-Transactions.html#working-with-batch-scripts) but I get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection OrientDB.RequestError: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.begin;let $susers = select from susers;return $susers
    Storage URL="plocal:/Users/amyth/projects/orient/orientdb-community-2.2.0/databases/konnect"
    at Operation.parseError (/Users/amyth/projects/konnect/node_modules/orientjs/lib/transport/binary/protocol33/operation.js:865:13)
    at Operation.consume (/Users/amyth/projects/konnect/node_modules/orientjs/lib/transport/binary/protocol33/operation.js:455:35)
    at Connection.process (/Users/amyth/projects/konnect/node_modules/orientjs/lib/transport/binary/connection.js:399:17)
    at Connection.handleSocketData (/Users/amyth/projects/konnect/node_modules/orientjs/lib/transport/binary/connection.js:290:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:172:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:542:20
```

For a script as simple as:

```
begin;let $susers = select from susers;return $susers
```

Am I doing something wrong ? or is this a bug ?

Comment: Hi, I try your case and I have same problem, can you open an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
db.query("begin;let $susers = select from susers;return $susers",{class: 's'}).then(function(res){
 console.log(res)
})
```

Seems that the docs has been changed recently leaving out the 
{class: 's'}

Comment: Thanks buddy. For pointing me in the right direction. Answer accepted.